# SAS EG SQL create a table named "SUCCESS" if 2 counts are identical

Tags: sql, if-statement, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I have two counts in my process, they should give the same result.

One is before a batch of queries, one is after, I want to make sure that the join operation haven't added or removed rows.

Right now I check these counts manually but I'd like a visual indicator that things went fine.

Thus I had the idea of writing a program that wille create an empty table named "SUCCESS" if these counts are equal, or a table named "FAILURE" if they're not.

Can you help me design the query that would achieve that ?

Here's what I have (not working obviously):

```
PROC SQL;
IF (SELECT count FROM WORK.count1) = (SELECT count FROM WORK.count2)
    CREATE TABLE WORK.SUCCESS
ELSE
    CREATE TABLE WORK.FAILURE
END
QUIT;
```

count1 and count2 are two tables that contain each a field named count, and one row with the value to be tested

Comment: Creating a table for this purpose sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I welcome other ideas, if there's another quick and visual way of doing this kind of test. I'm not used to SAS and I'm frustrated by the ergonomy of the thing, this would satisfy me for now.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Why not have a single additional table with the run date/time and the outcome?

Comment: I'd like to see it from the process map, clicking on an icon to see output takes around 5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use PROC SQL to do something like that.

```
data _null_;
  merge count1(rename=(count=count1)) count2(rename=(count=count2));
  if count1 ne count2 then call execute('data failure;run;');
  else call execute('data success;run;');
run;
```

Wouldn't it just be better to have the job to FAIL if the counts are different?  Not sure if this works properly in Enterprise Guide, but in a batch run you could just conditionally run the ABORT ABEND statement.

```
data _null_;
  merge count1(rename=(count=count1)) count2(rename=(count=count2));
  if count1 ne count2 then abort abend ;
run;
```

Comment: I get the impression `count` is pseudocode for the SQL function `count()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a table probably isn't the best way to do this, but you could create a macro that prints a message to the log.

```
%macro check_obs(d1, d2);

    data _null_;
        if 0 then set &d1 nobs=n;
        call symput('count1',n);
        stop;
    run;
    %put &count1;

    data _null_;
        if 0 then set &d2 nobs=n;
        call symput('count2',n);
        stop;
    run;
    %put &count2;

    %if &count1 = &count2 %then %put Obs equal;
    %else %put Obs not equal;
%mend;

/* Call the macro here */
%check_obs(work.count1, work.count2);
```

There may be an easier way to do this but all this macro is doing is storing the number of observations into the macro variables `count1` and `count2` and then checking if they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I'd normally do this is to show something useful on the Results window.

```
Title "Counts of Male and Female class members - check for equality";
proc sql;
  select
   (select count(1) from sashelp.class where sex='M') as male_count,
   (select count(1) from sashelp.class where sex='F') as female_count
   from sashelp.class where name='Alfred'
  ;
quit;
```

Obviously you would change this to query from table1 and table2.  You can actually leave the `from sashelp.class where name='Alfred'` if you want, that's not doing anything except providing a single row result set (it's similar to `from dual` for Oracle for example) because SAS PROC SQL requires a FROM.

Then use your title to tell you what you should be gleaning from the report.